# How can I find Bottom Rubber Feet Foot For MacBook Pro 15" A1398？

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

How can I find Bottom Rubber Feet Foot For MacBook Pro 15" A1398？
[image: Model:A1398]

I searched Amazon.com and ebay.com, can not find this model.

[image: Bad, needs to be replaced.]

Answer (score 3):

Apple actually has an article specifically about this, [right here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202450).  Apparently they have a rubber foot replacement kit which you can get if you contact them and request it.

Personally I would just find some soft-side velcro, felt, or some other craft material, cut out a few small circles with an xacto-knife, glue it on with Loctite (which is what Apple uses according to their article above) and call it a day.

If it really bugs you and you want someone else to cut out the little circles for you..

http://www.powerbookmedic.com/Macbook-Unibody-Feet-Replacement-Set-Black-p-23146.html

http://macdudu.en.alibaba.com/product/742059651-218052561/Rubber_Case_Foot_Feet_for_Macbook_Pro_retina_15_A1398.html

Comment: Has anyone ordered the feet from powerbookmedic for macpro model A1398? If so, were the feet the correct fit?

Answer (score 1):

As a former Mac Genius, I can tell you it's impossible to buy the feet separately as a replacement. You will have to get the bottom "plate" replaced. If it's under warranty, awesome, if not, it's less than $20 to get.

Comment: Just talked to a Mac Genius today at the store and he said the bottom plate replacement cost $120 Canadian.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this eBay link here:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/181701854491?ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1558.l2649

I hope it helps.